# ¿Que copilador puedo utilizar para copilar codigo de python3 en un solo archivo?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyinstaller

mi problema es e tuilizado diferentes copiladores tales como Pyinstaller, Nakite, xc_Freezer y py2exe para copilar mi codigo de python3 en un solo archivo .exe, con un icono.
Pyinstaller tiene todas estas opciones pero la bastantes antivirus lo detectan como virus y py2exe no tiene la capacidad de crear un solo archivo (ya que estoy utilizando codigo de tkinter). ¿Alguíen me podria decir un copilador que cumpla con lo que estoy buscando? gracias.
(este es un pequeño ejemplo de mi codigo:)

```
from tkinter import *

#---------------------------------------salir--------------------------------------

def salir(evento):
    root.destroy()

#----------------------------------------raiz--------------------------------------

root = Tk()
root.title("Proyecto de español")
root.attributes('-fullscreen', True)
root.bind('<F11>', salir)

#---------------------------------------organizador--------------------------------

organizador = Frame(root)
organizador.pack(fill="both", expand="True")
organizador.config(bg="#FF000E")


#----------------------------------Aviso Para Salir--------------------------------

salir_F11 = Label(organizador, text="Presione F11 Para salir del programa")
salir_F11.pack()


root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

¡Hola! La verdad que no tengo idea sobre compiladores de código, sin embargo buscando un poco por la red encontré un par de cosas que quizá puedan ayudarte:

> Siempre recibía falsos positivos con Pyinstaller de VirusTotal. Así es como lo solucioné:

> Pyinstaller viene con binarios de cargador de arranque precompilados para diferentes sistemas operativos. Te sugiero que los compiles tu mismo. Asegúrate de que todo sea consistente en tu computadora. Para Windows de 64 bits, instale Python de 64 bits. Descarga PyInstaller de 64 bits para Windows. Asegúrate de que Visual Studio ( VS) sea el correspondiente a tu Python instalado, y verifica a continuación:
> https://wiki.python.org/moin/WindowsCompilers

> Compila el cargador de arranque de Pyinstaller en tu computadora con VS. Actualiza automáticamente con run.exe, runw.exe, run_d.exe, runw_d.exe en DownloadedPyinstallerFolder \ PyInstaller \ bootloader \ Windows-64bit.
> Consulta a continuación para obtener más información sobre cómo compilar el gestor de arranque:
> https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/bootloader-building.html

> Al final, instala Pyinstaller.

> Dentro del directorio de Pyinstaller, ejecuta:
> python setup.py install

Todo esto fue dicho originalmente por el usuario @Sorush [En esta respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43777106/program-made-with-pyinstaller-now-seen-as-a-trojan-horse-by-avg) y de igual manera se brindan otras opciones en caso de que lo citado no funcione. Elegí traducir esta respuesta aunque no fuera anotada como la principal por el OP dado que muestra una solución con mas control por parte del creador del código que de los proveedores de antivirus.

P.D. Como sugerencia, entre las buenas practicas para el uso de python se recomienda no hacer el llamado a tkinter con el asterisco (*), se prefiere llamarlo como as tk.

Ejemplo(con tu mismo codigo):

```
import tkinter as tk

#---------------------------------------salir--------------------------------------

def salir(evento):
    root.destroy()

#----------------------------------------raiz--------------------------------------

root = tk.Tk()
root.title("Proyecto de español")
root.attributes('-fullscreen', True)
root.bind('<F11>', salir)

#---------------------------------------organizador--------------------------------

organizador = tk.Frame(root)
organizador.pack(fill="both", expand="True")
organizador.config(bg="#FF000E")


#----------------------------------Aviso Para Salir--------------------------------

salir_F11 = tk.Label(organizador, text="Presione F11 Para salir del programa")
salir_F11.pack()


root.mainloop()
```